# using local database in mobile app: reference error db not defined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, local-storage

I am developing an Android app using `Visual Studio`, `DevExtreme framework` and the `Cordova API`. My app has to work when it is online and offline. It connect to a database using `Odata Service` that covers the online part. For the offline part I would like to set up a local database storage. I have followed this example : http://blog.darkcrimson.com/2010/05/local-databases/ this is part of my code :

first I declared a action in my view model, this action is called when a button is clicked.

```
    var viewModel = {
    dataSource: dataSource,
    viewShown: handleViewShown,
    viewDisposing: handleViewDisposing,

    ladenDatabase: function (e) {
        dataSource.select("Oid", "Dossiernr");
        dataSource.load().done(function (result) {
            //make db and fill it with objects from sql database
            initDatabase();

            alert(result[0]);
        });
    }
}

    function initDatabase() {
    try {
        if (!window.openDatabase) {
            alert("Databases are not supported in this browser.");
        } else {
            alert("Databases are supported in this browser.");
            var shortName = 'DEMODB';
            var version = '1.0';
            var displayName = 'DEMO Database';
            var maxSize = 100000; //  bytes
            DEMODB = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
            createTables();
//                selectAll();
        }
    } catch (e) {

        if (e == 2) {
            // Version number mismatch.
            console.log("Invalid database version.");
            alert("Invalid database version.");
        } else {
            console.log("Unknown error " + e + ".");
            alert("unknown error " + e + "!");
        }
        return;
    }
}

function createTables() {
    alert("Creating Tables!");
    DEMODB.transaction(
    function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS page_settings(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, fname TEXT NOT NULL,bgcolor TEXT NOT NULL, font TEXT, favcar TEXT);', [], nullDataHandler, errorHandler);
    }
);
    prePopulate();
}

function prePopulate() {
    alert("PrePopulating !!!");
    DEMODB.transaction(
    function (transaction) {
        //Optional Starter Data when page is initialized
        var data = ['1', 'none', '#B3B4EF', 'Helvetica', 'Porsche 911 GT3'];
        transaction.executeSql("INSERT INTO page_settings(id, fname, bgcolor, font, favcar) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]]);
    }
);
}
```

The problem is when I run this code it first says : databases are supported in this browser so that's good. An error occurs when i hit this line :

```
DEMODB = openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize);
```

I get this error message :

> Reference error : DEMODB is not defined.

Where do I need to define this?

Comment: I have tried to add var DEMODB; in the upper section of the page and the error seems to be gone . Is this the wright way ? But now i get a new error :

    Error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: nullDataHandler is not defined'

Comment: I defined the functions NullDataHandler and errorHandler so i don't get the uncaught referenceError. I placed an alert in my nullDataHandler and noticed it always goes into this function. I assume something goes wrong in my executeSql function? But I have no clue what is going wrong there.